# SoapUI: Build DataSource Property from Groovy script

Tags: groovy, automation, datasource, soapui

I am trying to create property with all RoomTypeIds returned by soap response, like I am getting it from the grid, where all results go under the same property, so I can iterate over them, however when I run the script I get only the latest result multiple times, the usual naming of property is: result['property'].

```
for(int i = 1; (context.expand( '...ns1:RoomTypes[1]/ns1:RoomType[' + i + ']/@hotelRoomTypeId}' )) != ""; i++)  
{  
    def RoomTypeId = (context.expand( '...ns1:RoomTypes[1]/ns1:RoomType[' + i + ']/@hotelRoomTypeId}' )).toInteger()  
    result['RoomTypeId'] = RoomTypeId  
}
```

[Result In SoapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqTu0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `result` is a Map-like object. If that's the case, aren't you overriding the *RoomTypeId* during each iteration?

Here's a way to set the *RoomTypeId* property to a List:

```
for(int i = 1; String value = context.expand( "...ns1:RoomTypes[1]/ns1:RoomType[$i]/@hotelRoomTypeId}"); i++) {  
    if(!result['RoomTypeId']) result['RoomTypeId'] = []

    result['RoomTypeId'] << value.toInteger()
}
```